# GOTO from Try/catch block in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, goto

Yes, I know that GOTO is wrong and every time I use it a kitten dies ;) Still one thing makes me curious:

What if I use GOTO in try/catch block

```
Try
...some code...
Catch
...some code... 
  GoTo Label1
End Try
...some more code to be skipped if error
Label1:
...rest of code...
```

Do I understand correctly that the try/catch block will never get closed in the program and it may cause problems? Or not?

There seems to be also some OnError GoTo command but I don't have much experience with it. Maybe my code could be rewriten using it?

Comment: Reasoning about GoTo is hard, which is why it is strongly recommended to never use it.  You make it harder by talking about "closed" in the context of an exception.  That's not a meaningful phrase, exceptions are not like files or sockets.  Nothing needs to be "closed", by the time the code in the Catch block starts running, all of the side-effects of an exception are already completed.  And code will continue to run past the Catch block, whether you fall into it or jump into it.

Answer (score 6):

> Do I understand correctly that the try/catch block will never get closed

No, the try/catch block will be closed because you leave it. [It is okay to jump out of the try/catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c.aspx).

However, the code should be rewritten to:

```
Try
  ...some code...
  ...some more code to be skipped if error
Catch
  ...some code... 
End Try

...rest of code...
```

Comment: And if you need any code to run regardless if error or not after the Try then use a 'Finally' statement... Try - Catch - Finally - End Try

Answer (score 3):

It may be instructive to learn a little about the .NET framework internals:

> Exception handling is supported in the CLI through exception objects and protected blocks of code.

(CLI = Common Language Infrastructure)

> In the CLI, a method can define a range of CIL instructions that are said to be *protected*. This is called a *try block*. It can then associate one or more *handlers* with that try block. If an exception occurs during execution anywhere within the try block, an exception object is created that describes the problem. The CLI then takes over, transferring control from the point at which the exception was thrown, to the block of code that is willing
>    to handle that exception.

And this is all done in a declarative manner. So, basically, the `Try`, `Catch`, `End Try` etc items aren't emitted as *instructions* - the compiler says "if an exception happens in this range of instructions, here are the possible handlers to jump to". And it only consults this information when an exception occurs. So your concern:

> the try/catch block will never get closed

isn't valid because the one mechanism for leaving a protected region is... (drum roll please)... to move outside of that range of instructions. It doesn't matter *how* this is done - it could just be by running out of the end of the protected range, or via a `GOTO`, or via an exception.

---

First two quotes are from MS Partition I (section 12.4.2) and MS Partition II (section 19) documents available for download from [ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa569283.aspx)

Section 12.4.2 of Partition I also states:

> Protected regions, the type of the associated handler, and the location of the associated handler and (if needed)
>   user-supplied filter code are described through an Exception Handler Table associated with each method